# specify a tcsh file to source on shell initialization

Tags: tcsh

I am in a shared account, and would like to fire up a tcsh shell from a command line, and specify a custom .tcshrc file to source for this shell. tcsh is being run from a bash shell.

An equivalent to:

```
tcsh (go into new shell)
source /tmp/myRCFile.tcsh
```

Is there a way to specify the source command before entering the new shell with an alias? Or is there a better way?

Thanks much as I'm very tired of typing this.

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with spawning two shells (i.e. `$SHLVL` increasing by two):

```
tcsh -c 'source /tmp/myRCFile.tcsh; tcsh'
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but yes would like to just spawn one shell if possible

Comment: Understood. However, I doubt that this is possible in tcsh without modifying the startup file. You could alias the source command to make it easier. You could hook into `cd` to get [direnv](http://direnv.net/)-like directory-specific settings. You could also use [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) as proposed by [this SO answer] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/32454088/201318).